# How to count duplicates in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I use this pattern to find duplicates in column A from set `duplicates`:

```
duplicates = {1, 2, 3}
df[~df['A'].isin(duplicates)]
```

It works and returns me rows witout duplicates. But how to get count of duplicates?

I have tried these:

```
df[~df['A'].isin(duplicates)].count()
~df['A'].isin(duplicates).count()
```

And how to extract this count to variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_df = df[~df['A'].isin(duplicates)]
new_df['duplicate_values'] = new_df.duplicated('A')
new_df['duplicate_values'].sum()
```

Comment: So, you load all duplicates into a new frame then why do you use again duplicated?

Comment: I got this error:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  new_df['duplicate_values'] = new_df.duplicated(0)

Comment: first line will return new dataframe that contains values other than `{1, 2, 3}` and I expect this new dataframe to contain duplicate values, hence the use of `duplicated`.

Comment: For the second question, what is (0) ?

Comment: Zero (0) it is name of column it is int, for testing version

Comment: ok use: `new_df.loc['duplicate_values'] = new_df.duplicated(0)`